# Power Shell Scripts Backup older 15 days and Delete Log Files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

To those GURU on Power Shell Scripts Please help! =)

I am new to PS and I would like to ask your assistance how can i backup my log files older than 15 days to other folders.? Then eventually, those 15 days older will be deleted after the backup has been completed. After this i should start learning Power Shell =)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer fitting the powershell tag perhaps, but your could use "ForFiles" command:

http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

or perhaps

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem C:\Logfiles)
{
    if ($i.CreationTime -lt ($(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-15)))
    {
        Move-Item $i.FullName C:\Backup
    }
}
```

That's in powershell

Comment: @Sonn - Note that `$(Get-Date).AddDays(-15)` will give you 15 days ago with the current time. To get the beginning of the day 15 days ago use: `$(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-15)`